# How to remove duplicate items from an html dropdown using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, xml, drop-down-menu

I looked at a few threads, but with the code I have I was unable to make this work.  My jquery creates an html dropdown using information from an xml file.  I need to remove the duplicate options for the drop down.  This is not necessary but I need to also figure out how to just show the items in the category that is chosen from the drop down.

So right now it is displaying every category as many times as it appears in the xml.  The goal is to have it display each category once.  Also a tip on how to just show the items that contain that category would be greatly appreciated.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "XML/store.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find("info").each(function () {
                var option = $(this).find('category').text();

                $('#dropdown').append('<option>' + option + '</option>');



            });
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
<select id="dropdown">
    <option></option>
</select>
</form>
```

XML sample:

```
<products>
<info>
<image>
  <src>images/bosubalancetrainer.jpg</src>
</image>
<name>Bosu Sport Balance Trainer</name>
<brand>Bosu</brand>
<price>$85.95</price>
<category>Bosu Ball</category>
</info>
<info>
<image>
  <src>images/bosupro.jpg</src>
</image>
<name>Bosu Pro Balance Trainer</name>
<brand>Bosu</brand>
<price>$149.95</price>
<category>Bosu Ball</category>
</info>
<info>
<image>
  <src>images/bowflexdumbbell.jpg</src>
</image>
<name>552 Adjustable Dumbbells</name>
<brand>Bowflex</brand>
<price>$349.00</price>
<category>Weights</category>
</info>
<info>
<image>
  <src>images/bowflexbench.jpg</src>
</image>
<name>5.1 Series Bench</name>
<brand>Bowflex</brand>
<price>$259.00</price>
<category>Equipment</category>
</info>
</products>
```

Comment: did you see this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875607/filter-duplicate-options-from-select-dropdown

Comment: I tried implementing that and it failed to work.  I'm brand new to jQuery so that might be why :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check condition..

```
success: function (xml) {
      var arr = new Array();
      $(xml).find("info").each(function () {
           var option = $(this).find('category').text();
           if($.inArray(option, arr) > -1) {
               // Do nothing 
           }
           else {
               $('#dropdown').append('<option>' + option + '</option>');
                // Push into array
               arr.push(option);
           }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("select").each(function () {
       var selectedItem = $(this).find('option').filter(':selected').text();
       var selectedItemValue = $(this).find('option').filter(':selected').val();
       $(this).children("option").each(function(x){
           if(this.text == selectedItem && $(this).val() != selectedItemValue) {
               $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Beat this!!!