# Hide repeated option text value in select box using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery/Js how to hide option value for repeated text.

**`Main Goal is Remove repeated text option value from select box.`**

**I want to just hide Test1 and Test2 with id value 4,5 and 6 because their value are repeated in option box.**

```
<select name="finish" id="finish">
  <option value="">Finish</option>
  <option id="1" value="1">Test1</option>
  <option id="2" value="2">Test2</option>
  <option id="3" value="3">Test3</option>
  <option id="4" value="4">Test1</option>
  <option id="5" value="5">Test1</option>
  <option id="6" value="6">Test2</option>
</select>
```

jquery code is tring below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#finish').each(function(){
      //$(this).text().hide();
  }); 
});
```

Final result look like as below,

```
<select name="finish" id="finish">
  <option value="">Finish</option>
  <option id="1" value="1">Test1</option>
  <option id="2" value="2">Test2</option>
  <option id="3" value="3">Test3</option>
  <option id="4" value="4" style="display:none">Test1</option>
  <option id="5" value="5" style="display:none">Test1</option>
  <option id="6" value="6" style="display:none">Test2</option>
</select>
```

How to do this using javascript or jquery script.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a comment: this will not work in IE. So if you target it, you should find another solution.

Comment: ok let ignore for IE but how to do above case in firefox and chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter duplicate options from select dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875607/filter-duplicate-options-from-select-dropdown)

Comment: If you have that extra data in your options that means you are doing something wrong. For example if you get that data using sql then use SELECT DISTINCT to leave only unique options

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya can you tell us how do you get that repeated data? I bet that's a place that needs to be fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initailaize empty array `finishItems`.

Loop inside the select options using

```
$("select > option").each(function(){
});
```

If the option is not in list add it, if it exist removes it.

```
var finishItems = {};
$("select > option").each(function () {
if(finishItems[this.text]) {
     $(this).remove();
 } else {
     finishItems[this.text] = this.value;
 }});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var finishItems = {};
$("select > option").each(function () {
  if(finishItems[this.text]) {
     $(this).remove();
 } else {
     finishItems[this.text] = this.value;
 }});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="finish" id="finish">
  <option value="">Finish</option>
  <option id="1" value="1">Test1</option>
  <option id="2" value="2">Test2</option>
  <option id="3" value="3">Test3</option>
  <option id="4" value="4">Test1</option>
  <option id="5" value="5">Test1</option>
  <option id="6" value="6">Test2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will check it.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya Please accept the solution if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter()` to filter elements that have the same text as some previous element and one object to store text.

```js
var obj = {}, select = $('select');

select.html(select.find('option').filter(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  return !obj[text] ? obj[text] = 1 : false;
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="finish" id="finish">
  <option value="">Finish</option>
  <option id="1" value="1">Test1</option>
  <option id="2" value="2">Test2</option>
  <option id="3" value="3">Test3</option>
  <option id="4" value="4">Test1</option>
  <option id="5" value="5">Test1</option>
  <option id="6" value="6">Test2</option>
</select>
```

If you just want to add `display: none` to duplicates you can use `each` loop instead.

```js
var obj = {},select = $('select');

select.find('option').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text(); 
  !obj[text] ? obj[text] = 1 : $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="finish" id="finish">
  <option value="">Finish</option>
  <option id="1" value="1">Test1</option>
  <option id="2" value="2">Test2</option>
  <option id="3" value="3">Test3</option>
  <option id="4" value="4">Test1</option>
  <option id="5" value="5">Test1</option>
  <option id="6" value="6">Test2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this works .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var values231 = [];
  $.each($('option'), function(){ 
      var flag = false;
      var thishtml = $(this).html();
      for(var i = 0; i< values231.length; i++){
        if(thishtml == values231[i]){
          $(this).hide();
          flag = true;
        }
      }
      if(!flag){
        values231.push(thishtml);
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="finish" id="finish">
  <option value="">Finish</option>
  <option id="1" value="1">Test1</option>
  <option id="2" value="2">Test2</option>
  <option id="3" value="3">Test3</option>
  <option id="4" value="4">Test1</option>
  <option id="5" value="5">Test1</option>
  <option id="6" value="6">Test2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = []
$("#finish option").each(function(i, v) {
  if ($.inArray($(this).text(), arr) == -1) {
    arr.push($(this).text())
  } else {

    $(this).prop("disabled", true)
  }



})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="finish" id="finish">
  <option value="">Finish</option>
  <option id="1" value="1">Test1</option>
  <option id="2" value="2">Test2</option>
  <option id="3" value="3">Test3</option>
  <option id="4" value="4">Test1</option>
  <option id="5" value="5">Test1</option>
  <option id="6" value="6">Test2</option>
</select>
```

1. Have an array where you can put the text of each option
2. Check if the text is in array if yes then disable

Answer (score 1):

Try with `Array#includes()` and `Array#push` function .Push the `innerText` to array then check new element text is in array.If not present push with in array.else hide the respected element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr = [];
  $('#finish option').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).text().trim();
    if (!arr.includes(val)) {
      arr.push(val)
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="finish" id="finish">
  <option value="">Finish</option>
  <option id="1" value="1">Test1</option>
  <option id="2" value="2">Test2</option>
  <option id="3" value="3">Test3</option>
  <option id="4" value="4">Test1</option>
  <option id="5" value="5">Test1</option>
  <option id="6" value="6">Test2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to create an object which holds texts and if the option text is already registered it removes the option.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var elements = {};
  $('#finish option').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).val(), this);
      if(elements[$(this).text()]){
        $(this).remove();
      } else {
        elements[$(this).text()] = true;
      }
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple (vanilla) Javascript solution:

```
var options = document.getElementById('finish').options;
var contents = [];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (contents.includes(options[i].textContent)) {
        options[i].style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        contents.push(options[i].textContent);
    }
}
```

In IE, hiding options does not work. In that case, the only reliable way is deleting the elements from the DOM, and readding them if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var arr = [];
$('#finish option').each(function(){
    if( $.inArray($(this).text(), arr) == -1 )
  {
    arr.push($(this).text());
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/889bjct2/)

**Explanation:** Make an blank array in it, and push the unique value in it by checking if it already exist. And hide the options which are duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var seen = {};
$('#finish option').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (seen[txt])
        $(this).hide();
    else
        seen[txt] = true;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ru87nfy/

Answer (score 1):

To ensure distinct text only:

```
var seen = {} 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#finish').each(function(){
      if ( seen[ $(this).text() ] ) {
          $(this).hide();
      } else { 
          seen[$(this).text()] = true;
      }
  }); 
});
```

The `seen[ $(this).text() ]` part is `undefined` if not set, so only unseen text value will go to the `else`.

You can also tweak the condition for more complex logic.

Answer (score 0):

Loop in option and remove repeated value.

```js
var repeatText = {};
$("#finish > option").each(function () {
  if(repeatText[this.text]) {
     $(this).remove();
 } else {
     repeatText[this.text] = this.value;
 }});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="finish" id="finish">
  <option value="">Finish</option>
  <option id="1" value="1">Test1</option>
  <option id="2" value="2">Test2</option>
  <option id="3" value="3">Test3</option>
  <option id="4" value="4">Test1</option>
  <option id="5" value="5">Test1</option>
  <option id="6" value="6">Test2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add data in options from array. Find Unique in that array.

**JS**

```
 var array = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test1", "Test1", "Test2"]
  var json = _.uniq(array);
  $.each(json, function(i, value) {
    $('#finish').append($('<option>').text(value).attr({
      'value': i+1,
      'id': i+1
    }));
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="finish" id="finish" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Finish</option>
</select>
```

**Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sumitridhal/kg3pp367/**

Answer (score 0):

You could store a list of `text` in a new array (see `arrHide` in my code example), so in a loop through select's options you could check if current text is already in the `arrHide` array then hide the relative item.

See following, please:

```js
var arrHide = [];
$("#finish > option").each(function() {
  if($.inArray(this.text, arrHide) < 0){
    arrHide.push(this.text);
  }
  else {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="finish" id="finish">
  <option value="">Finish</option>
  <option id="1" value="1">Test1</option>
  <option id="2" value="2">Test2</option>
  <option id="3" value="3">Test3</option>
  <option id="4" value="4">Test1</option>
  <option id="5" value="5">Test1</option>
  <option id="6" value="6">Test2</option>
</select>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.